# Help with understanding a proof of existence of solutions

Tags: inequalities, stochastic-differential-equations, existence-theorems

In El Fatini and Boukanjime "[Stochastic analysis of a two delayed epidemic model incorporating Lévy processes with a general non-linear transmission](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/epdf/10.1080/07362994.2019.1680295?needAccess=true)" paper, can someone give a detailed explanation of the proof of Proposition 2.1 part (1)?

The highlighted part is what I'm having trouble with.

1. What does the $U(u)$ mean? is it "the smallest value of $V$ such that $x_i\geq u$ or $x_i \leq \frac{1}{u}$"?
2. I am confused with: $$V(S(0),I(0))+KT\geq \epsilon U(m),$$
   where $\epsilon \in(0,1)$. They let $m\rightarrow \infty$, which leads to $\infty>V(S(0),I(0))+KT=\infty$. Shouldn't it be $V(S(0),I(0))+KT=\infty=\infty \geq \epsilon\cdot\infty = \infty$? So the inequality actually holds and isn't a contradiction?

[image]

Comment: 1. Maybe this is what you mean, but I would rather phrase the description of $U(u)$ as follows: It is the infimum of $V$ on the set of $x$, which satisfy that $x_i \geq u$ or $x_1 \leq 1/u$ for $i=1$ or $i=2$. This is clearly related to the stopping time defined in (6), which is the stopping time for entering this set.

Comment: 2. The contradiction comes from two things: From the assumptions and the definitions we know that $V(S(0),I(0)) + KT$ is finite. From the derived inequalities on the other hand, if follows that it has to be larger than any bound. These two things do not go together. OK?

Comment: 1. is clear now. I still don't understand 2. as in the paper it states $$V(S(0),I(0)) +KT\geq U(m).$$ So when $m \rightarrow \infty$ then $V(S(0),I(0)) +KT = \infty$. But also when $m \rightarrow \infty$ then $U(m)=\infty$ so we have $\infty \geq \infty$, no?

Comment: This is another way of saying what I tried to say. The inequality just above says that *for any $m$" we have $V(S(0),I(0)) + KT \geq \varepsilon U(m)$. If this inequality is true for all $m$, then we can let $m$ tend to $\infty$. This does not change the left hand side, as it does not depend on $m$. But the right hand side tends to $\infty$. So the only chance that all these inequalities are true is that $V(S(0),I(0)) + KT=\infty$. Note that it does not make sense to say $U(m) = \infty$. For each specific $m>0$, this value is finite.

Comment: I meant $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} U(m) = \infty$ as, of course, we are talking about limits.

Comment: So? Yes, this side of the argument shows that the value has to be infinite. But please do not forget the other side of the argument, which is that from the definition of $V, S(0),I(0),K$, and $T$ we know that the value has to be finite. This is the desired contradiction.

Comment: Aha, I understand now, thank you Sir!